# How to show that the expression can be made arbitrarily close to 0?

Tags: real-analysis, ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor = \max\{z\in\mathbb{Z} : m\leq x\}.$

Let $z\in\mathbb{Z}.$

How to show that the expression $-\sqrt{2}z+\lfloor \sqrt{2}z \rfloor$ can be made arbitrarily close to $0$ (due to the choice of $z$)?

Comment: I guess you don't want $z=0$. Now, can you show that $\sqrt{2z}$ can be arbitrarily close to an integer?

Comment: @Benjamin Wang, no. I have no idea how to show it :(

Comment: Can you use ideas from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Continued_fraction ? Here's some theory about the convergents: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Infinite_continued_fractions_and_convergents

Comment: Simply choose $z=2$.

Comment: @Benjamin Wang, Thanks for the direction, I'll try to figure it out

Comment: @Doug I've corrected it